# How to find process that's using 100% of CPU

Tags: cpu, centos, cpu-usage

As i'm looking at htop and top i see that my processor usage is 100% allways. But i can not see any process that is using that much CPU. Htop shows me only 1-2 processes that use around 5% cpu time.

Is there a way to find the processes that use that much cpu time?

Here is the output of `ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -r -k1 | less`

```
%CPU   PID USER     COMMAND  
 0.8 20413 root     jsvc.exec -user tomcat -cp ./bootstrap.jar -Djava.endorsed.dirs=../common/endorsed -outfile ../logs/catalina.out -errfile ../logs/catalina.err -verbose org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap -security  
 0.3   631 mysql    /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid --skip-external-locking  
 0.2  3380 root     /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k restart -DSSL  
 0.2 24698 root     tailwatchd  
 0.2 22472 root     /usr/local/jdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/common/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start  
 0.1 32095 root     cpanellogd - processing bandwidth  
 0.0  9733 root     sleep 1m
```

Comment: Could you provide a cut&paste or window capture of the htop output you're seeing?   Best if it's sorted by 'CPU Usage' (press 'P'). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pcpu` doesn't do what you think.

From [UNIX man pages : ps ()](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps):

```
CODE    HEADER  DESCRIPTION

%cpu    %CPU    cpu utilization of the process in "##.#" format.
                Currently, it is the CPU time used divided by the time the
                process has been running (cputime/realtime ratio),
                expressed as a percentage. It will not add up to 100%
                unless you are lucky. (alias pcpu).
```

As you can see, `pcpu` doesn't measure the current CPU usage, but the average CPU usage since the process started. If a process has been running for a couple of days before it suddenly misbehaves, you won't be able to see that variation using the `ps` command.

In contrast, `top` shows the current CPU usage in the `%CPU` column.

From [UNIX man pages : top ()](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top):

```
k: %CPU  --  CPU usage
   The  task's  share  of  the  elapsed CPU time since the last screen
   update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time. In a true  SMP
   environment, if  'Irix  mode'  is Off, top will operate in 'Solaris
   mode' where a task's cpu usage will be divided by the     total  number
   of  CPUs.   You toggle 'Irix/Solaris' modes with the 'I' interactive
   command.
```

`top` automatically sorts processes by current CPU usage, so the first process should be the culprit.

Comment: hi, on http://pastebin.com/icvhUCcJ you can find output of my top command on server... i can see only 6 processes (it varies of course) that use around 4% CPU... where is the culprit? :D

Comment: In you paste, only `3.3%` of your CPU usage corresponds to CPU time spent in user processes (`us`), which explains why you can't find a process with elevated CPU usage. However, `38.8%` corresponds to CPU time spent on system/kernel processes (`sy`) and `57.9%` to CPU time spent on nice processes (`ni`). There might be a problem with the kernel. Try upgrading it.

Comment: i just thought that it would show up somewhere, like the kernel would have a generic process. And thanks for the hint to upgrade kernel. i will do that as soon as we will start migrating to new servers.